# Find Task returning methods which are not awaited

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, roslyn

I know that if you call a Task returning method without awaiting (`Task.Delay(1000);`) you will get the "Because this call is not awaited..." warning, but is there any way (by an extension or otherwise) to get a warning for tasks that are assigned to variables but not awaited? (This would include being used in parameters to another method call.

```
var a = Task.Delay(1000);
return;
```

Comment: You can do this with a code analyzer in Roslyn. There are several analyzers in the Visual Studio Extensions gallery that already give such warnings. I think Resharper also issues a warning for such cases

Comment: This my be possible for simple cases by writing a code analyzer for roslyn, but once you even get a little more complicated it is just too much data to parse to do it in a time efficient manner.

Comment: I was looking at writing a Roslyn analyser to do just this. It should just be a case of looking for any await, .Wait(), .Result, Task.WhenAll()'s that reference that variable, or not. But I was wondering if anyone had beaten me to it.

Comment: This is actually equivalent to the halting problem; you need to follow the path of that value through arbitrary logic.

Comment: You only have to solve the halting problem if you don't want to generate false positives. It's how much effort you're willing to expend to deal with edge cases to remove more false positives that you have to pick. E.g. `a.ContinueWith` has been called, is that good enough to say the original task has been handled?

Comment: In general yes, it requires the halting problem. But you could very much just ban task assignments like that, or at least say for any task variable assigned to, there has to be a await somewhere. It might be good enough for @wmbates' scenario.